# Linux sed replace comma at certain position

Tags: linux, csv, awk, sed

I have a csv with a weird format, I would like to change decimal values by a point and keep the comma as separator. The issue is that sometimes I have 3 commas and sometimes 4 commas.

For example:

```
30,-4,098511E-02
30,05,-4,098511E-02
66,7,-1,865433
```

I need to transform to:

```
30,-4.098511E-02
30.05,-4,098511E-02
66.7,-1.865433
```

I don't know if that's possible to do it with sed or awk.
I tried something like `sed -i 's/\(([0-9]+,?){1,2}),/\1./g' P7.csv > P7_test.csv` with no success

Comment: Most seds need a backslash before `+`, `{`, and `}`.

Comment: This is inherently ambiguous, how would you e.g. handle: `66,7,1`?

Comment: You state your data has 3 or 4 commas, but the sample you provide us currently has 2 or 3.  Please update  your question.

Comment: Don't you want `66,7,-1,865433` converted to `66.7,-1,865433` instead of `66,7,-1.865433` so your output is always 3 output columns? Or should `30.05,-4,098511E-02` actually be `30.05,-4.098511E-02` so there's always 2 output columns? It's hard to believe you'd want the output you show where which comma gets converted varies apparently haphazardly and the output is a mix of 2 and 3 column lines but if you do then tell us what the rules should be to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you know there are only 2 columns *and* the second column is always a floating-point number (when there are any), you can use this:

```
awk -F, 'NF == 3 { $0 = $1FS$2"."$3 } NF == 4 { $0 = $1"."$2FS$3"."$4 } 1' infile
```

Comment: Elegant solution.  Use filename provided by op?

Comment: @Thor, I really like your solution, as Allan said very elegant.

Answer (score 2):

You could easily do this tsk in `awk`. Please try following code written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
NF==3{
  match($0,/(^[^,]*),([^,]*),(.*$)/,arr)
  print arr[1],arr[2]"."arr[3]
  next
}
NF==4{
  match($0,/(^[^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),(.*)$/,arr)
  print arr[1]"."arr[2],arr[3]"."arr[4]
}
'   Input_file
```

***NOTE:*** In case you want to save output into `Input_file` itself then append  `> temp && mv temp Input_file` to above code.

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above `awk` code.

```
awk '                                            ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }                              ##Setting FS and OFS as comma in BEGIN section of this awk program.
NF==3{                                           ##Checking if there are 3 number of fields in current line then do following.
  match($0,/(^[^,]*),([^,]*),(.*$)/,arr)         ##Using match to match regex (^[^,]*),([^,]*),(.*$) to create 3 capturing group to be saved into arr array.
  print arr[1],arr[2]"."arr[3]                   ##Printing 1st element of arr followed by comma followed by 2nd element followed by DOT followed by 3rd element of arr.
  next                                           ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
NF==4{                                           ##Checking if there are 4 number of fields in current line then do following.
  match($0,/(^[^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),(.*)$/,arr) ##Using match to match regex (^[^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),(.*)$ to create 4 capturing group to be saved into arr array.
  print arr[1]"."arr[2],arr[3]"."arr[4]          ##Printing 1st element of arr followed by dot followed by 2nd element followed by comma followed by 3rd element of arr, followed by DOT followed by 4th element of arr.
}
'  Input_file                                    ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is internally inconsistent. I will assume if a line has 3 commas then we want to change the first and last comma to a period.  Otherwise the line has 2 commas and we only want to change the last comma to a period:

```
$ sed -E '/(,[^,]+){3}/ { s/^([^,]+),/\1./ }; s/,([^,]+)$/.\1/' P7.csv
30,-4.098511E-02
30.05,-4.098511E-02
66.7,-1.865433
```

I suggest you regenerate the data from the original source in an unambitious format if at all possible.  The heuristic you asked us to implement which may introduce (data) errors.

This invocation you mention will modify the file P7.csv and write a blank file P7_test.csv.  This is probably not what you want (where ... is some script):

```
sed -i ... P7.csv > P7_test.csv
```

Comment: The code works perfectly. Just I didn't notice, I have also values `42,35,18,15199` which are not transformed correctly, it outputs: `42,35,18.15199` instead of `42.35,18.15199`

Comment: The question changed so I updated answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sed:

```bash
cat file
30,-4,098511E-02
66,7,-1,865433
42,35,18,15199
30,05,-4,098511E-02

sed -E 's/^([0-9]*),([0-9])/\1.\2/; s/([0-9]),([0-9E-]*)$/\1.\2/' file

30,-4,098511E-02
66.7,-1.865433
42.35,18.15199
30.05,-4.098511E-02
```

Here `^([0-9]*),([0-9])` matches 2 digits at start separated by a `,` in capture groups 1 and 2. In replacement we place a dot between captured values.

Comment: @user979974: Check my updated answer with your input sample.

Comment: thanks a lot. I tried your code it works good just, for some lines, for example: `30,05,-4,098511E-02` it becomes: `30.05,-4,098511E-02` instead of `30.05,-4.098511E-02`

Comment: btw in your question in expected output you showed `30.05,-4,098511E-02` which is not what you want.